# Does NSURLConnection support FTP passive mode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking

I have troubles connecting to a FTP server (passive mode) from my iOS App.
I don't know if it's related to the ftp server (proftpd on linux 12.04), the port range or the client (I'm using NSURLConnection).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode` to `YES` in your stream?

Comment: Do you know how can I get CFStream ref from NSURLRequest to set this property?
(I propose NSURLRequest because it seems impossible with NSURLConnection)